# Exception message not in English using Intellij

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea

I can't seem to change the language on the exception messages in Intellij (Getting them in my native language). Everything else in the run log / output is in English.

I have checked the settings for any deviation from English but can't find any. I also added the line "-Duser.language=en" in .vmoptions.

**Example:** Got a FileNotFoundException

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\Users\SomeUser\SomeFilePath\SomeFile ***(Det går inte att hitta filen)***
```

Comment: How was the excpetion created? Through a Java application?

Comment: Yes, just made a simple Java application to recreate an exception. The (Det går inte att hitta filen) part can be translated to "The file cannot be found".

Comment: Have you tried to add "-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US" to VM options in your run configuration?

Comment: Yes I did as @Taras suggested which did not work

Comment: I meant you run configuration, not IDE .vmoptions file.

Comment: Also did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also need to change region in .vmoptions file:

```
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.region=US
```

This will override the default language and region settings for the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and may cause exception messages to be displayed in English.

Comment: It did not work

Answer (score 0):

Have to try to add below to "Help | Edit custom VM options".

```
-Duser.language=en
```